# MSACCESS updating field with tick marks

Tags: ms-access

I have a table with data I'm using in a VBA subroutine.  The entered data is "FlOOR AND DECOR".  My problem is ACCESS keeps updating "DECOR" like this "FLOOR AND DÉCOR"

So when I run my subroutine the data isn't found because my import data doesn't have the tick mark.  I really don't like the tick mark in the first place, so getting rid of it would be a blessing.

FLOOR AND DECOR  vs. FLOOR AND DÉCOR

I have not a clue on how to resolve.  So really haven't tried anything.  Don't even know where to start.

Comment: Check Settings and AutoCorrect.

Comment: Exactly where is accent mark added? In a textbox? Also look at Allow AutoCorrect property of textbox.

Comment: It is added after I press ENTER on a field in a table.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  I deleted the AutoCorrect entry.   Thank you so very much.